# Copy data from category and productions table with all of subsets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a category table : **tbl_category** as below

**id** is identity key

| id | parentid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | mobile |
| 2 | 2 | tablet |
| 3 | 1 | apple |
| 4 | 1 | samsung |
| 5 | 3 | iphone 12 |
| 6 | 4 | Galaxy S |

And I have a product table to which the latest category is attached. **tbl_productions** as below

**pid** is identity key

| pid | parentid | productname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | iphone 12 mini |
| 2 | 5 | iphone 12 pro |
| 3 | 6 | galaxy S 9 |
| 4 | 6 | galaxy S 10 |

---

Now: For example, I want to make a copy of the mobile category.

This category includes: iPhone and Samsung, each with an unspecified number of subsets.

And to make the data clear, I add the word "duplicate" at the end of their name, and finally the new data will be as follows.

New category data:

| id | parentid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | mobile |
| 2 | 0 | tablet |
| 3 | 1 | apple |
| 4 | 1 | samsung |
| 5 | 3 | iphone 12 |
| 6 | 4 | Galaxy S |
| 7 | 0 | mobile-duplicate |
| 8 | 7 | apple-duplicate |
| 9 | 7 | samsung-duplicate |
| 10 | 8 | iphone 12-duplicate |
| 11 | 9 | Galaxy S-duplicate |

And new productions data:

| pid | parentid | productname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | iphone 12 mini |
| 2 | 5 | iphone 12 pro |
| 3 | 6 | galaxy S 9 |
| 4 | 6 | galaxy S 10 |
| 5 | 10 | iphone 12 mini-duplicate |
| 6 | 10 | iphone 12 pro-duplicate |
| 7 | 11 | galaxy S 9-duplicate |
| 8 | 11 | galaxy S 10-duplicate |

(I have an unspecified number of categories and subcategories in the category table. I want to copy that category of subcategories and products by giving an ID. For example, I give the ID 4, which is for Samsung, to the query and perform the operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following an example which might help you with the categorys table - you can modify it for the second table.

I inserted an additional row in order to check a further level of parent-child-dependency. However, the line is commented for the time being.

Furthermore I changed the parentId of mobile and tablet to 0 since your final result shows the lines accordingly.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
   id int
  ,parentid int
  ,name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 0, 'mobile')
,(2, 0, 'tablet')
,(3, 1, 'apple')
,(4, 1, 'samsung')
,(5, 3, 'iphone 12')
,(6, 4, 'Galaxy S')
--,(7,6,'Galaxy S - Proto')

DECLARE @idToCopy int = 1
DECLARE @maxId int = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @t)

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT *
    FROM @t
    WHERE id = @idToCopy
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.parentid, t.name
    FROM @t t
    INNER JOIN cte c ON t.parentid = c.id
    WHERE t.id != @idToCopy
),
cteNew AS(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parentid, id) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT c.rn + @maxId AS IdNew
      ,ISNULL(n.rn + @maxId, 0) AS parentidNew
      ,CONCAT(c.name, '-duplicate') AS nameNew
  FROM cteNew c
  LEFT JOIN cteNew n ON n.id = c.parentid
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```